# isValidNumber google does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use this script took on GitHub

https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input

which allows to have in the input field for entering the phone number with the international prefix

there is also the example to be able to validate
http://jackocnr.com/lib/intl-tel-input/examples/gen/is-valid-number.html

I do not know what is wrong but also any number correct me always returns invalid
I also tried the same code of the page online, but something is wrong.
Suggested you have any?
Both codes do not work
Thank You

This is the html code of the site where I changed the url to get the files directly online

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Example: Validation</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jackocnr.com/lib/intl-tel-input/examples/css/prism.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jackocnr.com/lib/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css?1421726152408">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jackocnr.com/lib/intl-tel-input/build/css/demo.css?1421726152408">

              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jackocnr.com/lib/intl-tel-input/examples/css/isValidNumber.css?1421726152408">



          </head>

          <body>
            <a href="/intl-tel-input.html">Back</a>
            <h1>Example: Validation</h1>
            <p>Use public isValidNumber method (utilising Google&#39;s libphonenumber) to validate the telephone number on the change event.</p>

            <h2>Markup</h2>


            <h2>Result</h2>
            <div id="result">
              <input id="phone" type="tel">
        <span id="valid-msg" class="hide">✓ Valid</span>
        <span id="error-msg" class="hide">Invalid number</span>
            </div>

            <script src="http://jackocnr.com/lib/intl-tel-input/examples/js/prism.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://jackocnr.com/lib/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.js?1421726152408"></script>
            <script src="http://jackocnr.com/lib/intl-tel-input/examples/js/isValidNumber.js?1421726152408"></script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

this is my code html

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>International Telephone Input</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/intlTelInput.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/demo.css">
          </head>
          <body>
            <h1>International Telephone Input</h1>
            <form>
              <input id="phone" type="tel">
              <span id="valid-msg" class="hide">✓ Valid</span>
                <span id="error-msg" class="hide">Invalid number</span>
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

            <!-- Load jQuery from CDN so can run demo immediately -->
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="build/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
            <script>


              var telInput = $("#phone"),
              errorMsg = $("#error-msg"),
              validMsg = $("#valid-msg");

              $("#phone").intlTelInput({
                autoFormat: false,
                //autoHideDialCode: false,
               // defaultCountry: "auto",
                //ipinfoToken: "yolo",
                //nationalMode: false,
                //numberType: "MOBILE",
                onlyCountries: ['it', 'gb', 'fr', 'es', 'de'],
                //preferredCountries: ['cn', 'jp'],
                preventInvalidNumbers: true,
                utilsScript: "lib/libphonenumber/build/utils.js"
              });

            // on blur: validate
            telInput.blur(function() {
              if ($.trim(telInput.val())) {
                if (telInput.intlTelInput("isValidNumber")) {
                  validMsg.removeClass("hide");
                } else {
                  telInput.addClass("error");
                  errorMsg.removeClass("hide");
                  validMsg.addClass("hide");
                }
              }
            });

            // on keydown: reset
            telInput.keydown(function() {
              telInput.removeClass("error");
              errorMsg.addClass("hide");
              validMsg.addClass("hide");
            });

            </script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: even if I insert an exact number , always I get the message "Invalid number"

Comment: The first code is complete and is the one used in the link of the developer on github